# Array string in function error

Tags: c++, arrays, string

So, I need to salvage this large program for my assignment, but I cannot make sense of the error I'm getting for this string array in a function.
At the = of stockSymbol = """" 
I keep getting the error
'Error:a value type "const char *" cannot be assigned to an entity of type "std::string *"
I included where the string is defined and the function. Anyone have any ideas on what's happening and how to fix this?

```
int menu()

{
int actents = 0;

int opt = 0;

string stockSymbol[MAXENTS];

double stockShares[MAXENTS];

double stockPrice[MAXENTS];

int opt;

string opts;

void resetPortfolio(string stockSymbol[], double stockShares[], double stockPrice[], int & actents)

{
    // code logic to set all entries of the stock symbol array to ""
    stockSymbol = "\"\"";
    // code logic to set all entries of the other arrays to 0
    stockShares = 0;
    stockPrice = 0;
    // set the number of actual entries in the arrays (actents) to 0
    actents = 0;
    return;
}
```

Comment: Don't you need `"\"\"" ?

Comment: Because C++ is a bit weird, `string stockSymbol[]` in a function declaration makes `stockSymbol` a *pointer to a `string`*, not an array of `string`s, even though it looks like an array of `string`s.

Comment: I assume you meant '"\"\""' and put that there, but now it says the same error above except as an int cannot be assigned to std::string.

Comment: @immibis Do you know how I could go about fixing that?

Comment: @ReyH Unfortunately, you can't pass an array to a function, full stop. The usual workaround is to pass a pointer to the start of the array, and the number of elements in the array. Note that that isn't the only problem with your code.

Answer (score 1):

`stockSymbol`, `stockShares`, and `stockPrice` are all pointers to the first element of arrays.  You cannot just assign to them to set the values of their elements.  Instead you need to loop over the arrays and set the value of each element.

```
void resetPortfolio(string stockSymbol[], double stockShares[], double stockPrice[], int & actents)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < actents; ++i) {
        // code logic to set all entries of the stock symbol array to ""
        stockSymbol[i] = "";
        // code logic to set all entries of the other arrays to 0
        stockShares[i] = 0;
        stockPrice[i] = 0;
    }
    // set the number of actual entries in the arrays (actents) to 0
    actents = 0;
}
```

There are other problems with the code you posted.  `menu()` is never closed, and you never actually call `resetPortfolio()`.

Comment: Okay, thank you, this seemed to fix it and help me understand how I should have been coding the entries. And sorry, this was only a snid bit of the code, it's this big giant thing and I was trying to cut it down to what I thought was needed.

Comment: @ReyH it is good to cut away unrelated stuff but it is also important that the parts left behind make sense.

Answer (score 0):

Your function `menu` isn't closed.

```
string stockSymbol[MAXENTS];

double stockShares[MAXENTS];

double stockPrice[MAXENTS];
```

Are these supposed to be inside or outside `menu`?

`""""` means the string `""`. If you write 2 strings together, it means the concatenation of the strings.

To set fill the arrays with the value,

```
for(var i=0; i<MAXENTS; i++)
    stockSymbol[i]="\"\"";
for(var i=0; i<MAXENTS; i++)
    stockShares[i]=0;
for(var i=0; i<MAXENTS; i++)
    stockPrice[i]=0;
```